# JQuery FadeOut() callback timing

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

I have an MVC app where I am loading partial views within a series of tabs. I have an absolutely positioned DIV that I'm using as a loading indicator. For two of the tabs, it works perfectly. For the third one, it's instantly firing the callback function and not fading out the "ModalLoading" DIV.

NOTE: The "ModalLoading" div is not hidden. I even added the extra "stop" in there to make sure it's not firing because it's already faded out. I'm so confused. I've searched everywhere for something that might cause this. All of the tabs are using the exact same function and are called the same way. Does anyone have any ideas?

Thanks for your help!

Here is the JQuery code:

```
    $("#AssessmentNav ul li").click(function () {
        $("#AssessmentNav ul li").removeClass("active");
        $(this).addClass("active");
        LoadView($(this).data("view"));
    });

function LoadView(view) {
    $("#ModalLoading").fadeIn(250);
    $("#AssessmentContent").html('').load(RA.BASE_URL + "Assessment/" + view + "/" + AssessmentId, function () {
        $("#ModalLoading").stop(false, true).fadeOut(2000, function () { console.log("Ding fries are done!"); });
    });
}
```

Comment: try changing the second argument to false in .stop()

Comment: I did. I tried several variations including that one and this one: $("#ModalLoading").show().fadeOut(250);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually figured this out. After much pain, I found that a different partial view happened to have a div in it with the same ID "ModalLoading". So, when I called fadeOut, it found the other instance which was hidden. Because of that, fadeOut instantly fired the callback and did not fade out the div I wanted.

Mental Note: Check all partial views for conflicting IDs. Especially when the different views are developed by different people.